# Does the Stack Overflow XML dump data contain voters information?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, data-dump

I have got a version of the Stack Overflow dump data dated September 2011. In the votes file the lines are like this format:

```
<row Id="1" PostId="4" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2010-09-13" />
```

where `id` is the serial number, `postid` is the post that received the vote, and `VoteTypeId` is the vote type (in this case it is UpMod).

In this format I can not know what user voted on the post, is it normal? Or I have just got a bad dump; if so, where can I download a better version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Votes are anonymous, and the data dump has been processed to preserve that. Who voted is deliberately *not* included.

So yes, that's normal.

Comment: I see, for a research purposes, I need the voters id, I do not need neither their names nor the content of questions and answer (which guarantee also the anonymous votes. does such a version exists?

Comment: Nope, no such version exists.

Comment: @tammuz If you don't need any of the information associated with the ID, why do you need the ID? Are you studying user voting patterns?

Comment: @Asad: He wants 'Voter A' voted on these posts, but 'Voter B' voted on those posts info, where 'Voter A' and 'Voter B' are supposed to be anonymous (not connected to the users table). However, such info is rarely really anonymous; using statistics you can correlate that info to users anyway (think usual posting tags, for example).

Comment: @Asad: Exactly I am interested in user voting and trusting patterns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you might be right, even though I do not think that this is pretty easy, but it is out of my intentions :)

Comment: @tammuz: It may not be your intention, but who's to say someone else doesn't have that intention, and the know-how to do so? That's why the information is not included.